# Where clause not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent, laravel-5

i have problem the problem is Where Clause not work in my project, i make sure to follow instruction on laravel documentation but the data in my table is not show on my datatable, i hope you can help me.

> AbsenController@index

```
public function index()
{
    $absen = Absen::get()->where('level', '=', 'Siswa');
    return view('absen.index')->with('data', $absen);
}
```

> index.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $index => $value)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->nama }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->keterangan }}</td>
              <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['siswa.destroy', $value->id], 
                   'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                  {{ Form::submit('Hapus', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
                  <a href="{{ route('siswa.edit', $value->id) }}" class="btn 
                 btn-warning">Edit</a>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

[image: The record is not showing in my datatable]

The record is not showing in my datatable

[image: my Table]

But i have one record in my table
Thanks

Comment: I think, this `get()->where('level', '=', 'Siswa')` should be `where('level', '=', 'Siswa')->get()`.. And where is `nama` column in your database table?

Comment: @MilanChheda "nama" column i put in "siswa" table in my database but its already to many to one eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching records before filtering with where..

You should do:

```
$absen = Absen::where('level', '=', 'Siswa')->get();
```

instead.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem. And this is already commented above.

Comment: @MilanChheda have you tried var_dumping the value of  `$absen` to see if there is any content?